# Estimating covariance from single sample

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, inference, covariance

We have a sample distribution $p(x)$ and the iid sample $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. I have the two following random variables, calculated from $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$: 
$$A = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)$$
$$B = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(x_i)$$
where $f(x_i)$ and $h(x_i)$ are continuous functions.
Given only the sample $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, I need to calculate an estimate of the covariance $Cov(A,B)$.

I have written $Cov(A,B)$ as:
$$\mathbb{E}_{x_{1:n}}\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i) - \mu_{A} \right)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(x_i) - \mu_{B} \right)\right]$$

Since I have single $A$ and $B$ instances produced from the sample $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, it is not meaningful to directly apply the unbiased covariance estimator formula. The only meaningful approach seems to somehow produce synthetic $A$ and $B$ instances from the sample $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and then use the covariance estimator, doing some kind of bootstrapping. What methods I can use here, what can be a logical approach in this situation? Am I looking for any kind of guidance.

Comment: I haven't done bootstrapping before. Suppose it is really i.i.d, and you are only interested in the expectation but not the variance of the covariance between A and B. Maybe: Draw N samples from the sample distribution and call that one surrogate. Then, make a bunch of surrogates and calculate A and B for the surrogates. Finally, calculate the covariance between the distribution of A and distribution of B calculated from the surrogates. Alternatively, find the distribution of A and B in terms of p(x) and N, and then find the distribution of covariance between A and B.

Comment: Are you interested in the covariance between A and B over your sample that gives the p(x) or over the population that gives you the sample?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I am interested with an estimate of the covariance between A and B, which is calculated over all the $x$ population.